# How to build SQL query for associated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using PyODBC to fetch some data, since I am not fetching all data in my table, I need to write a query which grabs only rows which have associated columns.  For example my initial query is:

```
SELECT SRNumber FROM SO_SC_1 WHERE SRNumber LIKE '%1-%'
```

This returns the SRNumber values that I want.

Next I want to return the associated last edited user with this SRNumber. This column is named `last_edited_user`. What is the proper syntax to incorporate multiple queries into one for this scenario?  Basically I would like to use the initial query and grab all associated data for each SRNumber.

Comment: Just use `SELECT SRNUmber, LastEditedUser` . . . or whatever the column is called.

Comment: You need multiple columns in your select and multiple conditions in your where clause. See @Ala response below for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query all needed columns using their comma separated names

```
SELECT SRNumber, last_edited_user
FROM SO_SC_1 
WHERE SRNumber LIKE '%1-%'
```